# Prime ideals in ring of real analytic maps correspond to closed submanifolds?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, analytic-geometry, smooth-manifolds, analytic-functions

In affine algebraic geometry, prime ideals in a ring $R$ correspond to irreducible subschemes of $Spec(R)$. For a real, compact, smooth manifold $M$, each prime ideal in $\mathcal{C}^\infty(M)$ is contained in a unique maximal ideal (corresponding to a single point), so we can’t use prime ideals to understand submanifolds.

But what if we restrict to the ring $\mathcal{C}^{an}(M)$ of real, analytic functions on $M$? I understand that the zero sets of analytic functions are unions of submanifolds of lower dimension, so it seems like we’re on the right track. But **can it be shown (or proven false) that for all prime ideals $P$, the zero set $Z(P)$ is a closed, irreducible submanifold of $M$, and that for any closed, irreducible submanifold $N$ in $M$, $I(N)$ (the set of analytic functions vanishing on $N$) is prime in $\mathcal{C}^{an}(M)$?**

Note that I use “irreducible” to mean “unable to written as a finite union of closed *submanifolds*”, not just closed sub*sets*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whitney's umbrella provides a counterexample to your first statement. Let $M=\Bbb R^3$ and $P=(x^2-y^2z)$; then the zero set is not even pure-dimensional. $P$ is prime for the following reason: $\Bbb R^2$ maps to the Whitney umbrella by $\varphi:(u,v)\mapsto (uv,u,v^2)$ with real-analytically dense image. So if $fg\in P$, then pulling back we have that $\varphi^*(fg)=(\varphi^*f)(\varphi^*(g))$ is a function on $\Bbb R^2$ which is zero and real analytic functions on $\Bbb R^2$ are a domain. Thus one of $f$ and $g$ is already zero on the Whitney umbrella, and $P$ is prime.

The second statement is true. Suppose $f,g\in C^{an}(M)$ with $fg\in I(N)$. Then $N=V(f)\cup V(g)$ is a decomposition in to closed analytic subsets, and by irreducibility we have that one of $V(f)$ and $V(g)$ is all of $N$, so one of $f$ and $g$ is in $I(N)$.

Comment: Ah yeah that makes complete sense that zero sets could be slightly more general / include singularities of some form. Do you know of any references for something like “real analytic algebraic geometry”? I imagine you could get some notion of analytic resolution of singularities...

Comment: Sure, one place to start for the basic theory is "Topics on Real Analytic Spaces" by Guaraldo, Macri, & Tancredi. (Your guess on the terminology is pretty close, and you may also be interested to know Hironaka's original paper on resolution of singularities included a section on analytic spaces, so that's two things your intuition is doing well on.)